# Box2D how to give circles more sides?

Tags: box2d

I am wondering if there is any way to give CircleShapes more sides to make them more circular. I have some large circles that I need a bit more exact.

Comment: what are you using a square? b2CircleShape ?

Comment: Yes, a CircleShape

Comment: A circle in Box2D doesn't have sides. The shape is based on math using sin and cos. The larger the circle the more accurate that circle becomes as the larger numbers are less limited by the maximum decimal places of the floating point numbers used in calculations. However, as Box2D is based on MKS units object that move should be limited to 0.1 to 10 units in size.